# Method of joints

Tags: structural-engineering

Consider the space truss represented schematically in Figure 1. It has 21 struts and a fixed support at “A”. At joint “G”, it is applied a force vector with a component of -20 N, along the x-axis, and a component of 10 N, along the y-axis, as shown in Figure 1. Using the method of joints, calculate the forces for the struts converging at joint “E”, i.e. the forces for struts “EA”, “EB”, “EF”, “EG”, “ED” and “EH” and specify if the struts are in tension or in compression.

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework so you need to show some effort at a solution to prevent your question being closed as off-topic as we don't offer a free homework service. Use the edit link below your question.

Comment: I understand I just needed help on how to find the moment as I am very confused on how to answer that

Comment: OK. Use the [Edit] link to add that information into your question along with your attempt at the answer.